# How to open a popup window in angular 8 using socket.io nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io

I am implementing a video call application using angular 8 where on button click, I am executing a function that emits a socket event from front end to connected users in a namespace in node socket.io at back end level. As I am getting response to each connected online users as expected on front end. But I am not able to open a popup window on respective connected users browsers.

I want to achieve when click on video call button, should open a popup window on other online users browser indicating accept and reject buttons using socket.io.

following is code that i have done in front end angular 8.

```
onClickVideoCall() {
     console.log('send video call notification');
     this.socketService.emitMessage('send-video-call-invitation', { taskId: this.taskId, twilioRoomId: 
     this.currentChannel.sid });
     this.messageService.isVideoCallInvitation = true;
   }
```

following is socket event written in nodejs.

```
socket.on('send-video-call-invitation', async data => {
   nsp.to(#socketId).emit('send-video-call-invitation', { userId: id, taskId: data.taskId });
}
```

In above code I have retrieved socket Ids from database.

And catching response in ngOnInit() as follows.

```
subsribeVideoCallNotification() {
    console.log('observe new notification');
    const observable = new Observable<any>(observer => {
    this.socket.on('send-video-call-invitation', data => {
    observer.next(data);
});
return () => {
    this.logger.error('Some error while getting new notifications');
};
});
return observable;
```

}

```
<app-accept-reject-video-call *ngIf="messageService.isVideoCallInvitation" 
    (closeDialog)="messageService.isVideoCallInvitation=false">
</app-accept-reject-video-call>
```

As I am getting response in the console of each connected users browser but i want to open a popup window indicating accept and reject buttons. Popup is opening in my own browser which is not expected.

Anyone one having idea about the issue.

Comment: Couldn't see any code to open a popup, inside the subscription.

Comment: <p-dialog header="Twilio" [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" [style]="{width: '350px', minWidth: '200px'}" [minY]="70"
  [maximizable]="true" [baseZIndex]="10000">
  <p>Video call invitation!</p>
  <p-footer>
    <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Accept"></button>
    <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-times" label="Reject" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
  </p-footer>
</p-dialog>

above code refers to <app-accept-reject-video-call>